# convert table in a jpg image to excel using python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have a table which is a jpg image as in the link below and wanted to know how I could convert this into excel.

https://www.mining.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/TOP-50-Value-mining-companies-jumps-600-billion-from-covid-lows-.jpg

What library or open source software could be used along with python?

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt you can do it right of the bat. I would assume you'll need to using sole image extraction (deep learning) to get the information

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: I have updated the question to include what library or open source software can be used along with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend cropping the image such that only the table is visible. Secondly, you can use OpenCV to detect and convert it in the CSV file by using contours and corners detection. You can use this [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-detect-tables-in-images-using-opencv-and-python-6a0f15e560c3) as a starting point reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to perform OCR (optical character recognition). That can be done with OpenCV and Tesseract. The output is usually a structured document or sometimes even a database that can be loaded into Python again.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not simple and is called [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

I strongly suggest to find a different way to represent your data, an easy and common way is to use a format like JSON or CSV, but if you must you can try [Tesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/) to extract text from image. But it will require some pre and post processing.